# c++98 struct default to zero except one value

Tags: c++, struct, default-value

This is certainly related to a bunch of other questions which have been answered, but I have been unable to derive the answer for my specific case from them, largely because I'm not actually a programmer; I'm just an engineer who happens to have to write some code.

Here's the situation:

- I have a bunch of variables I'd like to collect together, probably into a structure.
- All but two I would like to initialize to zero; two specific variables (which don't happen to be the first two) need to be initialized to one.
- The actual names are unique and meaningful enough that using a vector wouldn't be appropriate, plus there are some doubles in there too. I'm keeping my example below simple for clarity.
- Because of the project I'm working on, I'm stuck with C++98, so even if C++11 has more elegant solutions, they won't work for me.

I am thinking something along these lines for the structure itself:

```
struct allFlags
{
    int flagAA;
    int flagAB;
    int flagAC;
    int flagAD;
    int flagAE;
    // ...
    // there's about 100 variables total
    // ...
    int flagZZ;
};
```

I want to have all the flags initialized to 0 except for `flagAD` and `flagAE`, which should be 1.

So first of all, I am not sure if I should use `typedef struct allFlags` or `struct allFlags`. Next, I am not sure if I should be creating a constructor (which I think only would apply in the case of no `typedef`?) or making the defaults happens when I instantiate the structure. I have seen things like this (which would be put inside the struct definition):

```
    allFlags() : flagAD(1), flagAE(1) { /*not sure of I'd need anything here*/ }
```

but I wouldn't want to have to list out all other ~98 variables by name individually in the constructor body to set them to zero. I have also seen things using `memset` which could potentially help, but I'm not sure the best way to do it.

And finally one additional related question is how to actually declare an instance of my structure (which results in the initial values I want). It looks like sometimes a `struct` is instantiated with the `new` keyword and sometimes is it treated more like a base data type, i.e. I have seen both of these in searching:

```
allFlags flagset1;
flagset2 = new allFlags;
```

I have also seen syntax which would be like this rather than using a constructor at all:

```
allFlags flagset3 = {}; // to zero all fields first
flagset3.flagAD = 1;
flagset3.flagAE = 1;
```

but I'd rather keep the instantiation as clean and simple as possible.

Please forgive the question. I have tried to do my homework before asking, but my C++ knowledge is mediocre at best and so some of the seemingly relevant answers I've found I either didn't fully understand or just raised more questions.

Comment: Is the struct a POD type?

Comment: C++ makes the `typedef struct` pattern unnecessary. `struct allFlags` is sufficient.

Comment: Aren't arrays supposed to solve these types of problems?  What am I missing?  If there were 200, 300, or 1,000 flags, you would create 200, 300, etc. separate variables?

Comment: I think the OP wants a specific unique name for each of them, so an array wouldn't work. Your point is correct, however, @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @NathanOliver - yes, the struct is a collection of simple data types.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - my actual variables are things like flg_Waypoint_Lat, flg_Waypoint_Lon, etc. which are much more meaningful than the example I posted for simplicity and would certainly be more meaningful than flag[3] and flag[5] or something like that.

Comment: You can still use an array. Just use an enum, constant, whatever to denote which flag you want.  `const int AA = 0; const int AB = 1;...int flags[100];  flags[AA] = 1;`, etc,  The initialization is done only once, and there are not 100 separate variables.  Basically there is no reason that I can think of to create 100 or more separate variables of the same type, used in the same context (all are int's and all denote some some sort of flag).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I hadn't been thinking along the lines of enumerated indices for an array. That might work but it still doesn't address the desire to declare things in a super compact way that initializes all but two to 0 (and those two specific ones to 1). Also, I'd still need a struct (though the array you suggest could be inside the struct) because there are a couple doubles in addition to the simple int flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel comfortable with using templates, you can use a class template to automate clean initialization of all member variables of `allFlags`.

```
// class template to help initialize members cleanly.
template <typename T>
struct flag
{
   // Constructors
   flag() : val(0) {}
   flag(T const& v) : val(v) {}

   // Automatic cast operators to T
   operator T& () { return val; }
   operator T const& () const { return val; }

   // Comparison operators
   bool operator==(flag const& rhs) const { return val == rhs.val; }
   bool operator!=(flag const& rhs) const { return val != rhs.val; }
   bool operator<(flag const& rhs) const { return val < rhs.val; }

   T val;
};

typedef flag<int> IntFlag;
typedef flag<double> DoubleFlag;

struct allFlags
{
   // Initialize all flags bug flagAD to zero.
   allFlags() : flagAD(1) {}

   IntFlag flagAA;
   IntFlag flagAB;
   IntFlag flagAC;
   IntFlag flagAD;
   IntFlag flagAE;
   IntFlag flagZZ;
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   allFlags f;
   std::cout << f.flagAA << " " << f.flagAD << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1
```

Comment: A variation of this proposal with the addition of using enumeration for an array of flags seems to be the winning combination. It was more up front code than I anticipated but it works beautifully from the user perspective.

Comment: @Mike, glad I was able to help. Use of `enum`s always raises red flags in my mind. If you want to see whether the `enum` can be replaced by something else, or you want to get general feedback on how to improve your code, please visit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and post a question there. Make sure to read up on [their guidelines on what to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before creating a post.

Comment: @R Sahu - per your suggestion I have asked for some suggestions on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163167/input-data-integrity-checking).

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question quite well:

```
allFlags flagset3 = {}; // to zero all fields first
flagset3.flagAD = 1;
flagset3.flagAE = 1;
```

It is clean, and very clear about your intentions.  Later, when someone else has to read your code they will understand exactly what you are trying to do.

It is similar to what you see in device driver programming:

```
registerX = 0 | 1 << BIT2 | 1 << BIT3;
```

Comment: To the OP: If the same three lines are used in multiple places, it will be better to put them in a function and use the function.

Comment: _"very clear about your intentions"_ - Only if your intent is to require every client of `allFlags` to know how to initialize an instance of `allFlags` rather than encapsulating that information in the constructor where it belongs.

Comment: As Captain Obvlious stated, it would require those three lines of code every time rather than one. The instantiation of `allFlags` happens in customer wrapper code so my strong preference would be to take care of it in a way that the customer doesn't need to do anything special if possible.

Comment: Then you definitely want to create a constructor that sets the variables.   Another option, as suggested by R Sahu is to create an initialization function.